# How can I add reference to a variable defined in previous function in LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I'm new to LLVM IR and I'm implementing PL0 language. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/0

I'm generating the testfile as following:

```
const a = 10;
var b, c;

procedure check1;
var dd;
   procedure check2;
       c := 2;
begin
   dd := 1
end;

begin
    b := -1024+53*(-514-766)/93+100;
    c := b
end.
```

And the LLVM IR I generated is like this:

```
; ModuleID = 'LLVM Module'

define void @__global_main_entry__() {
BlockUnitEntry:
  %b = alloca i32
  %c = alloca i32
  store i32 -1653, i32* %b
  %b1 = load i32* %b
  store i32 %b1, i32* %c
  ret void
}

define void @check1() {
ProcedureEntry:
  %dd = alloca i32
  store i32 1, i32* %dd
  ret void
}

define void @check2() {
ProcedureEntry:
  store i32 2, i32* %c
  ret void
}
```

I got a painful error here (at destruction):

```
While deleting: i32* %c
Use still stuck around after Def is destroyed:  store i32 2, i32* %c
test004_llvm_generate: /files/Install/LLVM_Framework/llvm/lib/IR/Value.cpp:79: virtual llvm::Value::~Value(): Assertion `use_empty() && "Uses remain when a value is destroyed!"' failed.
```

I guess that using variable `c`(defined in `__global_main_entry__`) in procedure `check2` adds a ref in llvm::Value, when destructing `__global_main_entry__` the ref at `check2` is causing the error.

I do not know how to solve the problem, and if you have time to be specific, please~

(Moreover, except for the official documentation of llvm. Are there any more resources on LLVM? I found that most tutorials are outdated.)

My full list of code is here: https://github.com/adamcavendish/PL0Compiler

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your IR is malformed - you cannot refer to an instruction from the body of a function different from the one in which the instruction appears, so referring to `%c` in `@check2` is illegal. The failure just happened to occur during module destruction, but it can occur in other circumstances as well.

In general, I recommend running `opt -verify` on your IR if you're not sure it's legal, it will give you nice error messages. [My Eclipse plugin](http://amishne.github.io/llvm-ir-editor/) might also help if you want to experiment with IR to see when it is and isn't legal.

As for a solution, it looks like you should create a [global variable](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#global-variables) to represent `c`, not an instruction. Then you can `store` into it and `load` from it in every function in the module.

Comment: How about `check2` reference to `check1`'s variables? Global variables won't solve the problem.

Comment: Does it look like a closure here? or maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @Adam Didn't quite understand your question. There's no concept of nested functions or closures in LLVM IR. If you want to share something between multiple functions you have to find a way to model it in the IR - using globals is the simplest solution I can think of. Another option is with parameters.

Comment: Maybe I'll try the parameters~